# .htaccess and php file

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

So, when I put in my .htaccess file which contains the following:

```
# Use PHP5 php.ini as default
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5 .php

AcceptPathInfo On

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [L,QSA]
```

The server tries to download the PHP file instead of executing it. When I remove the .htaccess file, everything works fine and the PHP files execute.

Answer (score 5):

I'd remove the `AddHandler` directive. Leave this to the server config.

Everything else looks fine.

Comment: +1 the AddHandler for .php force the download instead of executing. I've tried to remove that line and everything works fine. Ciao!

Answer (score 0):

It could very well be the

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5 .php
```

Are you including this because your server is setup to not run PHP5 by default?

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue in the end, I had the entire thing set up correctly. There is a bug in PHP5, that had happened due to some of the discontinuing support of $_SERVER['ORIG_PATH_INFO']. This is not true in windows servers, however in PHP 5.4.2 (Linux Distro) ORIG_PATH_INFO is not supported any more, only PATH_INFO. A report has been made about this. But all is up and running. Thanks for your guys' help and responses.